# How do you clean and forward fill a multiple day 1 minute time series with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with 1 minute stock data spanning multiple days. Each day runs from 9:30 to 16:00.

Some of the minutes in the time series are missing:
(here 2013-09-16 09:32:00 and 2013-09-17 09:31:00 are missing)

```
2013-09-16 09:30:00,461.01,461.49,461,461,183507
2013-09-16 09:31:00,460.82,461.6099,460.39,461.07,212774
2013-09-16 09:33:00,460.0799,460.88,458.97,459.2401,207880
2013-09-16 09:34:00,458.97,460.08,458.8,460.04,148121
...
2013-09-16 15:59:00,449.72,450.0774,449.59,449.95,146399
2013-09-16 16:00:00,450.12,450.12,449.65,449.65,444594
2013-09-17 09:30:00,448,448,447.5,447.96,173624
2013-09-17 09:32:00,450.6177,450.9,449.05,449.2701,268715
2013-09-17 09:33:00,451.39,451.96,450.58,450.7061,197019
...
...
```

With pandas, how do I forward fill the series so every minute is present? I should look like this:

```
2013-09-16 09:30:00,461.01,461.49,461,461,183507
2013-09-16 09:31:00,460.82,461.6099,460.39,461.07,212774
2013-09-16 09:32:00,460.82,461.6099,460.39,461.07,212774 <-- forward filled
2013-09-16 09:33:00,460.0799,460.88,458.97,459.2401,207880
2013-09-16 09:34:00,458.97,460.08,458.8,460.04,148121
...
2013-09-16 15:59:00,449.72,450.0774,449.59,449.95,146399
2013-09-16 16:00:00,450.12,450.12,449.65,449.65,444594
2013-09-17 09:30:00,448,448,447.5,447.96,173624
2013-09-17 09:31:00,448,448,447.5,447.96,173624 <-- forward filled
2013-09-17 09:32:00,450.6177,450.9,449.05,449.2701,268715
2013-09-17 09:33:00,451.39,451.96,450.58,450.7061,197019
...
```

It also needs to account for if multiple consecutive minutes are missing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I copied your first 4 lines into a dataframe:

```
Out[49]:
                    0         1         2       3         4       5
0 2013-09-16 09:30:00  461.0100  461.4900  461.00  461.0000  183507
1 2013-09-16 09:31:00  460.8200  461.6099  460.39  461.0700  212774
2 2013-09-16 09:33:00  460.0799  460.8800  458.97  459.2401  207880
3 2013-09-16 09:34:00  458.9700  460.0800  458.80  460.0400  148121
```

then

```
df1 = df.set_index(keys=[0]).resample('1min', fill_method='ffill')
df1

Out[52]:
                            1         2       3         4       5
0                                                                
2013-09-16 09:30:00  461.0100  461.4900  461.00  461.0000  183507
2013-09-16 09:31:00  460.8200  461.6099  460.39  461.0700  212774
2013-09-16 09:32:00  460.8200  461.6099  460.39  461.0700  212774
2013-09-16 09:33:00  460.0799  460.8800  458.97  459.2401  207880
2013-09-16 09:34:00  458.9700  460.0800  458.80  460.0400  148121
```

This will also deal with multiple missing values and forward fill them.

So if I have data like

```
2013-09-17 09:30:00,448,448,447.5,447.96,173624
2013-09-17 09:33:00,451.39,451.96,450.58,450.7061,197019
```

and do the same thing as before this gives:

```
Out[55]:
                          1       2       3         4       5
0                                                            
2013-09-17 09:30:00  448.00  448.00  447.50  447.9600  173624
2013-09-17 09:31:00  448.00  448.00  447.50  447.9600  173624
2013-09-17 09:32:00  448.00  448.00  447.50  447.9600  173624
2013-09-17 09:33:00  451.39  451.96  450.58  450.7061  197019
```

The key thing here is you must have a datetimeindex, if you want to keep it as a column then you can just set `drop=False` in `set_index`.

Comment: I have a similar question but the code you shared in this post didn't work for my case, could you please help me with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58313391/valueerror-cannot-reindex-a-non-unique-index-with-a-method-or-limit Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This might work slightly better for you as it takes into account different days such that you don't have to fill for each day:

Just creating the dataframe:

```
list1 = [["2013-09-16 09:29:00","461.01","461.49","461","461","183507"],
["2013-09-16 09:31:00", "460.82", "461.6099", "460.39", "461.07", "212774"], 
["2013-09-16 09:34:00", "460.0799", "460.88", "458.97", "459.2401", "207880"], 
["2013-09-17 09:35:00", "458.97", "460.08", "458.8", "460.04", "148121"]]

cols = ['date','price1','price2','price3', 'price4', 'price5']

df = DataFrame(list1, columns=cols)
```

Setting the index to be the date column:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

Reindexing and filling the holes, then forward filling the resulting NaN values, then dropping all times outside of 9:30AM to 4:00PM:

```
df2 = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq='Min')).ffill().ix[df2.index.indexer_between_time(pd.datetime(year=1,month=1,day=1,hour=9,minute=30).time(), datetime.time(16))]
```

Those statements can be broken out sequentially:

First, reindex the dataframe so that your index corresponds to your starting date/time through your ending date/time with a frequency of 1 minute:

```
df2 = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq='Min'))
```

This will create a lot of NaN values where the new index didn't line up with the old one. We fill this with ffill (forward fill), though there are other options out there:

```
df2.ffill(inplace=True)
```

Then finally, strip out the times that are outside your 9:30AM to 4:00PM time range:

```
df_final = df2.ix[df2.index.indexer_between_time(pd.datetime(year=1,month=1,day=1,hour=9,minute=30).time(), datetime.time(16))]
```

Because .time() doesn't take 9.5 and the documentation is kind of sparse, I just created a datetime object with the time value set to 9:30AM and then used .time() to grab this. There's a better way, I'm sure.