# How to resample using forward fill python

Tags: python, pandas

My Dataframe df3 looks something like this:

```
    Id           Timestamp         Data    Group_Id    
0    1     2018-01-01 00:00:05.523 125.5   101 
1    2     2018-01-01 00:00:05.757 125.0   101 
2    3     2018-01-02 00:00:09.507 127.0   52  
3    4     2018-01-02 00:00:13.743 126.5   52  
4    5     2018-01-03 00:00:15.407 125.5   50
                    ...

11   11    2018-01-01 00:00:07.523 125.5   120 
12   12    2018-01-01 00:00:08.757 125.0   120 
13   13    2018-01-04 00:00:14.507 127.0   300  
14   14    2018-01-04 00:00:15.743 126.5   300  
15   15    2018-01-05 00:00:19.407 125.5   350
```

I wanted to resample using ffill for every second so that it looks like this:

```
    Id           Timestamp         Data    Group_Id    
0    1     2018-01-01 00:00:06.000 125.00    101 
1    2     2018-01-01 00:00:07.000 125.00    101 
2    3     2018-01-01 00:00:08.000 125.00    101 
3    4     2018-01-02 00:00:09.000 125.00     52 
4    5     2018-01-02 00:00:10.000 127.00     52 

                    ...
```

My code:

```
def resample(df):
    indexing = df[['Timestamp','Data']]
    indexing['Timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(indexing['Timestamp'])
    indexing =indexing.set_index('Timestamp')
    indexing1= indexing.resample('1S',fill_method='ffill')
    # indexing1 = indexing1.resample('D')
    return indexing1
indexing = resample(df3)
```

but incurred error

```
ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit
```

I don't quite understand what this error mean. @jezrael from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792933/resampling-error-cannot-reindex-a-non-unique-index-with-a-method-or-limit) suggested using `drop_duplicates` with `groupby`. I am not sure what this does to the data as it seems there are no duplicates in my data? Can someone explain this please? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is caused because of the following:

```
    Id           Timestamp         Data    Group_Id    
0    1     2018-01-01 00:00:05.523 125.5   101 
1    2     2018-01-01 00:00:05.757 125.0   101
```

When you resample both these timestamps to the nearest second they both become
`2018-01-01 00:00:06` and pandas doesn't know which value for the data to pick
because it has two to select from. Instead what you can do is use an aggregation function
such as `last` (though `mean`, `max`, `min` may also be suitable) in order to 
select one of the values. Then you can apply the forward fill.

Example:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table(StringIO("""    Id           Timestamp         Data    Group_Id    
0    1     2018-01-01 00:00:05.523  125.5   101 
1    2     2018-01-01 00:00:05.757  125.0   101 
2    3     2018-01-02 00:00:09.507  127.0   52  
3    4     2018-01-02 00:00:13.743  126.5   52  
4    5     2018-01-03 00:00:15.407  125.5   50"""), sep='\s\s+')
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp']).dt.round('s')
df.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True)
df = df.resample('1S').last().ffill()
```

Comment: Thanks@cosmic_inquiry, what should I do if the Dataframe is df3?

Comment: In your code: 

`indexing1= indexing.resample('1S',fill_method='ffill')` 

---> 

`indexing1 = indexing.resample('1S').last().ffill()`